# How do I remove/stop Visual Studio 2013 from running as Administrator?

Tags: visual-studio, uac

When I click on the **Visual Studio 2013** icon, `UAC` asks me if I want to run it as Administrator and, when I click OK, it works. Now I need to **restore the default behavior**. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

I found that all of my large programs were running as administrator. To fix this, go to User Accounts in Control panel. Choose Change User Account Control settings. My settings were set to the lowest level; I changed to the second from top, Default-Notify me only when programs try to make changes to my computer.
Press OK.
Restart your computer, and the programs should no longer be opening as administrator.

Comment: after spending my two days to fix this problem and found your answer which  is working for me

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to go into the Properties for the program. Under Advanced, there's a checkbox that says "run as administrator".

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Visual studio shortcut. You'll get this window:
[image]

Click on `Advanced` button and uncheck the box 'Run as administrator'.

[image]

Comment: Sorry @Sam but the "Run as administrator" option is already unchecked... I'm also using Windows 8 and, when the UAC prompts me, the full path points to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe", but the Program Name is "devenv_2.exe"... I cannot find this one...

Comment: @CesarZaneti When you say the program name is `devenv_2.exe` where do you see that?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2017 also still does this, but there real answer (for me) is in the post below - if User Access Control is disabled (never notify) then Visual studio always runs in administrator mode (even when run as administrator is unchecked in advanced properties of the shortcut) and therefore Visual Studio debug programs cannot access network files while running.  Microsoft do not list this as a cause.

see

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55787/vs-2017-always-running-as-administrator.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally enabled 'always run as administrator' after trying to attach a debugger to a process. As a result, the 'Advanced' properties of the shortcut/devenv.exe did not have the 'Run as Admin' box checked.

The solution was to go to Tools --> Options --> VSCommands 12 (click Open Configuration) --> IDE Enhancements --> General. There is a box "Always start Visual Studio with elevated permissions"; uncheck that to revert to the regular start-up without administrator rights.

[Location of VSCommands in Options.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjTl2.png)

[Location of elevated permissions checkbox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WFN6.png)

Comment: Note - VSCommands is a plugin for VS so not everyone has it.

Answer (score 0):

delete reg valur of
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

devenv.exe
like
D:\program\programmation\vs2022\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).